# Physical back button in a Master Detail Page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to go back to the previous page when the physical back button is pressed in a Master Detail environment. I have override the OnBackButtonPressed and tried to capture the last page but I get the exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" .

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Please post your `OnBackButtonPressed` implementation!

Comment: protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count-1]);
            return false;
        }